# Update my fork of a github repo, to include submodules?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

A friend of mine has written an irc bot, and has the code on github. I made a fork, and wrote a few plugins and pushed to my fork. The owner of the original repo moved the plugins folder to a submodule (I don't even really get that, I've never really used git) and fetching and merging failed, and I couldn't figure out what went wrong.

So I deleted my fork, and forked it all over again, but when I did `git clone {my github fork}` I had an empty plugins folder. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or what's the right way to fork a repo that has a submodule thing in it. :/

@manojlds answer below does grab the submodule and grab the stuff to put in the plugins directory, but if I try to add a file and push I can't because it's pointing at the original submodule. I've forked the submodule now too, I just don't know how to make my main repo point to my fork of the submodule instead of the upstream submodule.

Comment: **See also:** [Fork github repo with submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50337342/forking-github-repo-with-submodules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

( or you can clone using the `--recurse-submodules` option)

and the plugins folder will be populated. If you don't understand about submodules, read about them here: http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html

Comment: If I fork the original repo, will that work on my fork? I guess I'll find out.

Comment: This doesn't quite work, my fork points to the plugins submodule from the original repo, which I can't push to.

Comment: I just made a fork of the submodule repo and push from that folder. I did find instructions elsewhere that I will be giving a shot tonight. If it works, I will add that as answer.