# Fork github repo with submodules?

Tags: github, git-submodules, git-fork

I'm trying to fork a github repo which uses several sub-modules. If I just fork the repo, the submodules are still referencing the original submodules (i.e., the submodules themselves arent forked). There are too many submodules for me manually fork them all! Is there a way to fork all the submodules too?

Also, if possible I'd like to be able to update the submodules automatically if there are changes to them. Whats the best way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to fork the submodules? Do you want to actually make changes to their code too? What you're describing is the expected behaviour. Also note you have to explicitly update submodules.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I need to update their code too! Sorry, what do you mean by explicitly update submodules?